# Let X be an n element set

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $X$ be an n element set, and let $A_1, ..., A_m$ be not
>   necessarily distinct, nonempty subsets of $X$. Prove that there exists
>   a subset from the list such that every element of this subset is
>   contained in at least $m/n$ sets among $A_1, ..., A_m$.

I have spent quite a time to come up with something but I am stuck. My first idea was to create a random variable $O_x$ so it represents the number of occurences for a given number $x$. I was able to see $E[O_x] \geq m/n$ but the rest didn't go as I expected.

Now I think of another approach. It would be to calculate the probability of having 1 element among $m/n$ sets and raising that expression to power of $k$-- the cardinality of the wanted set, if I could show it is greater than zero it should be cleared, right?

There is also proof by contradiction. If you assume the result is false, then this means for all $A_i$, there exists some $x \in A_i$ such that x is contained in at most $m/n$ sets among $A_1,...,A_m$. I think with this maybe I can show $|\cup A_i| < m$, but this is a contradiction as $A_1,...,A_m$ is guaranteed to be at least $|m|$ since they are all non-empty.

Anyway, I think I am lost on this one and I would kindly ask for a hint or a directive.

Comment: Is it $m\ge n?$

Comment: @mfl It is not given in the question, but I think if you take $m$ less than $n$, the claim still holds.

Comment: @bof D'oh silly me, ill delete my comment!

Comment: Assume it were not true.  Try to prove that that would mean $|\cup_{i=1}^m A_i| > n$.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I am also working on contradiction. Just to be sure, is the negation of the claim "for all $A_i$, there exists an $x\in A_i$ s.t $x$ is contained in at most $m/n$ sets among $A_1, ..., A_m$"?

Comment: First, the statement you're trying to provr is obviously true if $m\le n$; the interesting cases are when $m\gt n$, so let's assume $m\gt n$.

Comment: Second, **of course** $|\bigcup A_i|\lt m$; in fact $|\bigcup A_i|\le n$ since $\bigcup A_i\subseteq X$. So what?

Comment: I do't know what you mean by "$A_1,\dots,A_m$ is guaranteed to br at least $|m|$ since they are all non-empty." If you meant to say $|A_1\cup \cdots A_m|\ge m$, no, that does **not** follow. It would follow if they were nonempty and **disjoint** but nobody said they were disjoint. If they were disjoint, no element could belong to more tha one of them.)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos My bad! I meant to close **a different question** (now closed) as a duplicate of that old question, but I accidently voted to close this unrelated question. I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false for $m=0$ so let's assume $m\gt0$, which I'm sure is what you intended.
Write $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$.

For $x\in X$ let $I_x=\{i\in[m]:x\in A_i\}$.

Let $B=\{x\in X:|I_x|\lt\frac mn\}$.

If $B=\emptyset$ any $A_i$ will work, so let's assume $B\ne\emptyset$. Then
$$\sum_{x\in B}|I_x|\lt\sum_{x\in B}\frac mn=|B|\frac mn\le|X|\frac mn=m$$
and so
$$\left|\bigcup_{x\in B}I_x\right|\le\sum_{x\in B}|I_x|\lt m.$$
Therefore we can choose an index $i\in[m]$ such that $i\notin\bigcup_{x\in B}I_x$, which means that $A_i\cap B=\emptyset$, which means that $|I_x|\ge\frac mn$ for every $x$ in $A_i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to understand the last sentence though. How do we conclude the "for all" part? Besides, my approach in the end was to assume the negative, retrieve the $<m$ part, and conclude it's a contradiction since it should be greater than or equal to $m$. Would this be a valid proof also?

Comment: In the last sentence I can conclude that $|I_x|\ge\frac mn$ for every $x$ in $A_i$ because, if it failed for some $x$ in $A_i$, then for that $x$ we would have both $x\in A_i$ and $|I_x|\lt\frac mn$, that is, $x\in A_i$ and $x\in B$, contradicting the fact that $A_i\cap B=\emptyset$.